# tables in pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the following table and I need to make a new empty table and write a procedure using pl/sql to copy all data from the following table to the empty one:

```
  PRODUCT_ID   PRICE
  ---------- ----------
     1         50
     2         100
     3         3000
```

Help please

Comment: No need for a stored procedure: `create table new_table as select * from existing_table`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: You are fast ...

Comment: I need this in pl/sql .. is it the same statement? begin...end

Comment: I need the same statement in a procedure, tried to add a variable but did'nt work?

Comment: *I have the following table in oracle pl/sql* where is your table ?

Answer (score 1):

In stored procedure you can't create table in normal way, you need to execute from a string. Command: Execute `"create table example_table ( PRODUCT_ID number,PRICE number)';` Execute `"(string to create a table)"`

Insert its only avaible on execute to. Execute "(string insert)"

Answer (score 0):

A procedure isn't probably necessary. The code you are looking for would be something like

```
 create table example_table
(
PRODUCT_ID number,
PRICE number
);
insert into example_table (PRODUCT_ID, PRICE)
select PRODUCT_ID, PRICE from original_table
```

Comment: is this valid in pl/sql??

Answer (score 0):

This example is as per your requirements, copy it and change the column names. Its valid **PL/SQL** for **Oracle 11g**:

```
CREATE TABLE a_horse_with_no_name
( 
  col_horse_id numeric(10) not null,
  col_horse_name varchar2(50) not null,
  col_horse_breed varchar2(50),
  CONSTRAINT horse_pk PRIMARY KEY (col_horse_id)
);
```

Comment: This example is as per your requirements, copy it and change the column names. Its valid PL SQL. Oracle 11 g

Answer (score 0):

I understand that You want create a table inside PL/SQL procedure. You can do this using normal Oracle syntax like: create table etc... but you need to use it with
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement like: EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create table as select * from employee';

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems017.htm

After EXECUTE IMMEDIATE you must specify string in ' ' (apostrophes) You can also use a varchar2 variable (for example concatenated with other variables);